# how would i loop through an array to see if the user input variable(number) is equal to a element in the array and replace that element with a "@"

Tags: java, arrays

```
//my array(arrayAlphabetizer) is an int[] with random int with a capacity = the users name and surname
//allow the user to enter a value from arrayAlphabetizer element to search for

Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("please enter a value from the array to search for");
String search = input.nextLine();

//change input into int
int number = Integer.parseInt(search);

//loop through the array to find the value
for (int i = number; i <= arrayAlphabetizer.length; number++) {

    if (i <= number) {
        arrayAlphabetizer[i] = 0;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayAlphabetizer));
    } else {
        System.out.print(i);
    }
}
```

I've tried this and multiple other methods but nothings is working

Comment: `int i = number; i <= arrayAlphabetizer.length; number++` looks weird. and you check `i <= number`, seriously? when do you want to break the loop? It's really hard to post an answer, because I have no idea what do you want to do. you said your array holds names, right? what does `arrayAlphabetizer[i] = 0` do?

Comment: No need for a stressed reply, if your able to read then i said my array is an int array that hold random number

Comment: The user has to enter a number

Comment: If the number is equal to a digit in the array that didgit must be replaced with a "@"

Comment: Sorry sir. after the edit, the comment at the top of the code block looks better. You can check your initial version. My fault.

Comment: No problem, sorry im still new to coding in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting i = to number at the start of your loop. Your if statement will be executed in the first iteration of the loop. I think you want to start your loop at i = 0. Also I needs to be less than the length of the array, not less than or equal to.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
     if(array[i] == number)
          System.out.println(**whatever you want to print**);
     else
          System.out.println(**whatever you want to print);

}
```

You are trying to add a char into an int array which does not work. Are you sure you need to do that?

I hope this helps. Your question was a bit unclear and I cannot comment yet to ask for clarification so just respond if you have questions.

Comment: I have to replace the element that is equal to the user input with a "@"

Comment: You cannot add a char into an int array

Comment: Sorry my assignment says that and its poorly constructed

Answer (score 0):

int number = Integer.parseInt(search);

for (int i = 0; i <= arrayAlphabetizer.length; number++)
 {

```
if (number == arrayAlphabetizer[i]) 
{
    arrayAlphabetizer[i] = 0;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayAlphabetizer));
} else {
    System.out.print(i);
}
```

}